# Detailing query for split by month

Tags: sql-server

I have the following MS SQL query:

```
SELECT DNIS, COUNT(*) AS Numbers
  FROM I3_IC.dbo.CallDetail_Viw WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE CallDirection = 'Inbound'
   AND CallType = 'External' 
   AND InteractionType = 0
GROUP BY DNIS
ORDER BY DNIS;
```

Which returns a list like this:

```
DNIS           Count

+12013317062   34

+12018841142   1

+12019771912   1

+12025594026   72
```

This is over a period of 2 years. I would like a break-down per month

This is the layout of the DB I get this data from (some fields ommited)

```
CallId
CallType
CallDirection
LineId
RemoteNumberFmt
RemoteNumberCallId
InitiatedDate
InitiatedDateTimeGmt
ConnectedDate
ConnectedDateTimeGmt
TerminatedDate
TerminatedDateTimeGmt
DNIS
CallEventLog
```

The InitiatedDate and InitiatedDateTimeGmt fields are the ones that hold the date-time server based ad GMT based like this: `2013-02-11 23:01:26.000`

Any suggestions appriciated.

Comment: Do you need to break it down by month _and_ year, or is it okay if entries for a particular month in the first year and the same month in the second year are grouped together?

Comment: It should be grouped by year to see if there is an increase or decrease of numbers called.

Answer (score 0):

So group it by month.  Is there something I'm missing in your question?

```
SELECT DNIS, YEAR(InitiatedDate) as [Year], MONTH(InitiatedDate) as [Month], COUNT(*) AS Numbers
  FROM I3_IC.dbo.CallDetail_Viw WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE CallDirection = 'Inbound'
   AND CallType = 'External' 
   AND InteractionType = 0
GROUP BY DNIS, YEAR(InitiatedDate), MONTH(InitiatedDate)
ORDER BY DNIS, YEAR(InitiatedDate), MONTH(InitiatedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to extract the month and year from the `InitiatedDate` field and then include those values in the `GROUP BY`. You can also use those functions in the `ORDER BY` as well.

```
SELECT DNIS, COUNT(*) AS Numbers, DATEPART(mm, InitiatedDate) AS Month, DATEPART(yyyy, InitiatedDate) AS Year
  FROM I3_IC.dbo.CallDetail_Viw WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE CallDirection = 'Inbound'
   AND CallType = 'External' 
   AND InteractionType = 0
GROUP BY DNIS, DATEPART(yyyy, InitiatedDate), DATEPART(mm, InitiatedDate) 
ORDER BY DNIS, DATEPART(yyyy, InitiatedDate), DATEPART(mm, InitiatedDate) ;
```